# How to assign excel macro to command button in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro written in the Excel workbook which is assigned to a button. I now create a new form in VBA and try to assign the same code to a command button. 
This is a code to navigate through the specified URL and extract information to my excel workbook. It works well for first 10 records, but later, it gives me the error **"Permission Denied"** at "`For Each TRelement In TRelements`" line of code.

Please help me resolve this problem.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim URL As String

    Dim HTMLDoc As Object



    Dim IE As Object
    Dim TRelements As Object
    Dim TRelement As Object
    Dim InputElements As Object
    Dim InputElement As Object


    Dim r As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim offSet As Integer
    Dim maxOffSet As Integer


    URL = "https://www.gebiz.gov.sg/scripts/main.do?sourceLocation=openarea&select=rfiId"
    Sheet1.Cells.ClearContents
    'Sheet1.Range("A:F").ClearContents

    'Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    offSet = 0
    r = 0
    k = 0

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    'While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

    'Set HTMLdoc = IE.Document


    'With IE
        IE.navigate URL
        IE.Visible = True
         'Wait for page to load
        'While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            'DoEvents
        'Wend

        Do While IE.Busy
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop


        Set InputElements = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
        For Each InputElement In InputElements
            If InputElement.getAttribute("name") = "strBtnLast" Then
                maxOffSet = CInt(Split(Split(InputElement.getAttribute("onclick"), "Navigator(")(1), ")")(0))
            End If
        Next
        While offSet <= maxOffSet
            offSet = offSet + 10
            Set TRelements = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            For Each TRelement In TRelements

                If TRelement.className = "row_even" Or TRelement.className = "row_odd" Or TRelement.className = "header_subone" Then
                    i = 0
                    For Each Child In TRelement.ChildNodes
                        Sheet1.Range("A1").offSet(r, i).Value = Child.innerText
                        i = i + 1
                    Next
                    r = r + 1
                End If
            Next
            If offSet <= 10 Then
                Sheet1.Rows(1).Delete
                Sheet1.Rows(1).Delete
                r = r - 2
            End If
            If offSet > 10 Then
                Sheet1.Rows(offSet - 8).Delete
                Sheet1.Rows(offSet - 8).Delete
                Sheet1.Rows(offSet - 8).Delete
                r = r - 3
            End If
            IE.document.parentWindow.execScript "submitHTMLTableNavigator(" + CStr(offSet) + ");"

            'While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                'DoEvents
            'Wend

            Do While IE.Busy
                Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
            Loop

        Sheet1.Range("A:F").WrapText = False
        IE.Quit
    Wend
    'End With
End Sub
```

I am using Excel 2010.

Thank you.

Comment: You close IE befoew Wend ... Move after. The second Cycle not found the object.

Comment: What is your actual problem? A question title "How to assign macro to a button" does not indicate the actual problem you're having (i.e., the `Permission Denied` error/warning).

Comment: The problem is as follows: This is a macro code. Now, when I create a user form in VBA, I copy this code and paste it under the CommandButton in VBA. The code runs fine for 10 entries and then aborts giving me the mentioned eror message.

Comment: I need your help to modify/edit this code such that it runs on a button click on the user form, just as it does when I run the macro.Thanking you in advance.